# Same make command fails in macOS, but succeeds in Linux

Tags: linux, make, macos, gnu-make

I'm using below `Makefile` and `make publish` fails on macOS while succeeding in Linux (alpine, Ubuntu, Debian) with the below error:

```
$ make publish
"docker images" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker images --help'.

Usage:  docker images [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

List images
"docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker inspect --help'.

Usage:  docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]

Return low-level information on Docker objects
=> Publishing release image to some_image:tag ...
=> Publish complete
```

`make publish` pushes previously built Docker image `some_image:tag` with `make image_build`.

Makefile is below:

```
ORG_NAME ?= some_name
REPO_NAME ?= some_name
 
CHECK := @bash -c '\
  if [[ $(INSPECT) -ne 0 ]]; \
  then exit $(INSPECT); fi' VALUE

DOCKER_REGISTRY ?= [some_docker_registry]

.PHONY: build image_build tag login logout publish

build:
    ${INFO} "Building artifacts..." 
    ${INFO} "Building artifacts complete"

image_build:
    ${INFO} "Building images..."
    @ docker build -t $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME) .
    ${INFO} "Building complete..."

tag:
    ${INFO} "Tagging release image with tags $(TAG_ARGS)..."
    @ $(foreach tag,$(TAG_ARGS), docker tag $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME):latest $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME):$(tag);)
    ${INFO} "Tagging complete"  
 
login:
    ${INFO} "Logging in to Docker registry $$DOCKER_REGISTRY..."
    @ docker login -u $$DOCKER_USER -p $$DOCKER_PASSWORD $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)
    ${INFO} "Logged in to Docker registry $$DOCKER_REGISTRY"
 
logout:
    ${INFO} "Logging out of Docker registry $$DOCKER_REGISTRY..."
    @ docker logout $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)
    ${INFO} "Logged out of Docker registry $$DOCKER_REGISTRY"
 
publish:
    ${INFO} "Publishing release image to $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME)..."    
    @ $(foreach tag,$(shell echo $(REPO_EXPR)), docker push $(tag);)
    ${INFO} "Publish complete"

IMAGE_ID := $$(docker images -q $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME):latest)

# Repository Filter
ifeq ($(DOCKER_REGISTRY), docker.io)
    REPO_FILTER := $(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME)[^[:space:]|\$$]*
else
    REPO_FILTER := $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME)[^[:space:]|\$$]*
endif

# Introspect repository tags
REPO_EXPR := $$(docker inspect -f '{{range .RepoTags}}{{.}} {{end}}' $(IMAGE_ID) | grep -oh "$(REPO_FILTER)" | xargs)

# Cosmetics
YELLOW := "\e[1;33m"
NC := "\e[0m"
 
# Shell Functions
INFO := @bash -c '\
  printf $(YELLOW); \
  echo "=> $$1"; \
  printf $(NC)' SOME_VALUE

# Extract tag arguments
ifeq (tag,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  TAG_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
  ifeq ($(TAG_ARGS),)
    $(error You must specify a tag)
  endif
  $(eval $(TAG_ARGS):;@:)
endif
```

Wonder how to debug such issues and what could be the cause?

Tried to remove `latest` from line `IMAGE_ID := $$(docker images -q $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME):latest)`, but nothing happens:

```
$ make publish
=> Publishing release image to some_image:tag
=> Publish complete
```

`make` version on macOS:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Comment: Did you try on macOS with a newer version of GNU `make`?  Version 4.3 is available via Homebrew (installs as `gmake` if you do `brew install make`).

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. Just tried `gmake` and got the same error as with `make`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Actually after going through the Makefile one more time, I noticed that the "docker" command is complaining about a missing argument which means that it was not able to find the image you previously built

```
publish:
    ${INFO} "Publishing release image to $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME)..."
    ${INFO} "$(IMAGE_ID)"
    @ $(foreach tag,$(shell echo $(REPO_EXPR)), docker push $(tag);)
```

```
 $ make publish
"docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker inspect --help'.

Usage:  docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]

Return low-level information on Docker objects
=> Publishing release image to ****...
=>
=> Publish complete
```

If the image exists, the publish step would work properly

```
 $ make publish
=> Publishing release image to ***** ...
The push refers to repository [*****k]
90f9b3de67de: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:af045c36b459f251b41b2db6b98320b7fdc1d6a2146b17a15344ec0e0a89b6f5 size: 527
=> Publish complete
```

So you need to make sure that the "image_build" step is executed beforehand